# write debug messages in c to a file?

Tags: c, file, debugging

How can I write debug messages to file?

I am using:

```
void printLog(const char* mylog)
{
  #ifdef DEBUG

  FILE* pFile = fopen("mylog.txt", "a");
  fprintf(pFile, "%s\n",mylog);
  fclose(pFile);

  #endif

}
```

But how can I write commands in order to debug?

EDIT:

I mean , like I know in android ,you state for example `Log.i("MyActivity", "MyClass.getView() — get item number " + position);`.

Can I write something similar in c to a file?
A variable maybe ,an error etc.

I am using :  `gcc -g -DEBUG -o myexec myfile.c`

Comment: What do you mean by the actual question, i.e. "write commands in order to debug"? Please clarify, I just can't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think he wants a simple way of printing to file like say: myDebug("This goes to file");

Comment: @unwind:I updated .Yes,something like "Cool_Coder" wrote

Comment: You can define the macro 'DEBUG' in your code or compiler option.

Comment: If the DEBUG macro is defined, you can just call `printLog("some message");`. Are you saying you want to be able to call printLog() with multiple arguments, like `printLog("Some message", someVar, ...)`?

Comment: @Yuan:I am ,but I must use my function first in my code.

Comment: @Markku K:Yes,in a file.

Comment: First, change `-DEBUG` to `-DDEBUG` in your gcc command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do formatting, you can just use [`vfprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf) which is like `printf()` but prints to a file and with "wrapped" arguments:

```
void printLog(const char *fmt, ...)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  FILE* pFile = fopen("mylog.txt", "a");
  if(pFile != NULL)
  {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, fmt);
   vfprintf(pFile, fmt, args);
   va_end(args);
   fclose(pFile);
  }
#endif
}
```

Then you can use this like:

```
printLog("you have %d attempts left", numAttempts);
```

or whatever.

You can also `#define` a macro for the actual call, and compile it all out, of course. As written above, the calls will remain but the function being called will become empty. A clever compiler might optimize out such calls, but you can never be sure.

Assuming C99, such a macro might look like this:

```
#if defined DEBUG
#define LOG(fmt, ...)    printLog(fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define LOG(fmt, ...)    /* empty when debugging disabled */
#endif
```

Comment: How would you `#define` a macro in this case if you're using var args?